# Magento PayPal Post Back Bug

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment, debug, server

Maybe anyone can help solve this issue.
Everything worked fine ages, and yesterday, PayPal post back failed. It stopped updating any statuses.

Log is showing

```
[postback_to] => https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
[postback] => mc_gross=1.00&invoice=100002123&auth_exp=08%3A29%3A30+Oct+19%2C+2014+PDT&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&address_status=unconfirmed&item_number1=test&payer_id=8EUEYETHYRST8&tax=0.17&address_street=%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2&payment_date=08%3A29%3A30+Sep+19%2C+2014+PDT&payment_status=Pending&charset=UTF-8&address_zip=dsfsdf&mc_shipping=0.00&mc_handling=0.00&first_name=Sergey&transaction_entity=auth&address_country_code=LV&address_name=%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2+%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2&notify_version=3.8&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=Info%40eurofishshop.com&address_country=Latvia&num_cart_items=1&mc_handling1=0.00&address_city=%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2&verify_sign=ALBe4QrXe2sJhpq1rIN8JxSbK4RZAc6KHII6HCE8Yo15IkQfFCf9w2Yp&payer_email=ianjanho%40gmail.com&mc_shipping1=0.00&parent_txn_id=&txn_id=1WA86899Y17300749&payment_type=instant&remaining_settle=10&auth_id=1WA86899Y17300749&last_name=Yakovel&address_state=J%C4%93kabpils&item_name1=test&receiver_email=Info%40eurofishshop.com&auth_amount=1.00&quantity1=1&receiver_id=BU6HTDF6LYK4L&pending_reason=authorization&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=0.83&mc_currency=EUR&residence_country=LV&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=&auth_status=Pending&ipn_track_id=b4311d9ee7e6&cmd=_notify-validate
[postback_result] => HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 285
Expires: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 15:30:16 GMT
Date: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 15:30:16 GMT
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;paypal&#46;com&#47;cgi&#45;bin&#47;webscr" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;df9b7b5c&#46;1411140616&#46;418048a
</BODY>
</HTML>

    [exception] => PayPal IPN postback failure. See paypal_unknown_ipn.log for details.
    [__pid] => 26563
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854207/access-denied-on-paypal-ipn-verification

Maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and the link that Sergey posted did help me. Let me share my solution.

The fix should be applied to the app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php file (copy it to local of course).

Find the `protected function _postBack(Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface $httpAdapter)` and change the line

```
$httpAdapter->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $this->_config->getPaypalUrl(), '1.1', array(), $sReq);
```

with the following:

```
$httpAdapter->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $this->_config->getPaypalUrl(), '1.1', array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: something-here'), $sReq);
```

Comment: you should try to override Core files rather than copying them locally.

Comment: In the 1.9.0.1 Core Code there is the "Connection: Close" included in the parameters. So it will be enough to add this to the Parameter.

Comment: Is this still a bug in Magento? If so then plz log it at Magento LTS https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues